# How to get distinct values from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm afraid I don't understand collections and data structures enough to process similar questions referring to a hash set. I currently have a loop that in a program that randomizes indexes within an array. The original array passed into the method consists of all prime numbers less than 1,000.

Not including the full program as it's part of a larger homework assignment.

My problem is that the if statement I created is printing out numbers repeatedly even though I thought I coded it to only print out the number if the number is already not in the array.

Can someone point out the mistake in my logic?

```
public static void shuffle(int[] intArray, String name)
{
    assert intArray != null : "null!";
    long seed = name.hashCode();
    Random random = new Random(seed);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int random_m = random.nextInt(intArray.length);
        int random_n = random.nextInt(intArray.length);

        int temp = intArray[random_m];
        intArray[random_m] = intArray[random_n];
        intArray[random_n] = temp;

        int zeroIndex = intArray[0];
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(!myList.contains(zeroIndex))
        {
            System.out.println(zeroIndex);
        }
        myList.add(zeroIndex);
    }
}
```

Partial example of output:

5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821
5821

Comment: Inner loop? There is only one loop.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your list is reset on every iteration of the for-loop... so you have no state of previous numbers.

Comment: a new instantiation of `myList` will occur for every iteration of the `for` loop - useless

Comment: Also, your list only ever uses the zeroeth element of the array without any regard for the random indeces generated.

Comment: The goal of this part of the assignment is only to focus on the zeroth element

Comment: All i can see is that you are doing the same thing for 1,000 times.

Comment: Your code is equal to `myList.add(zeroIndex); delete myList;`

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will adjust the scope as well as the code, then.

Comment: @CyrusLeung, `nextInt(value)` is an *exclusive* upper-bound, so the unmodified `intArray.length` is correct

Comment: @Immersive my bad, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 4):

```
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This Line of Code Creates New memorySpace for myList Through every iteration , so every time you iterate through the loop the myList values will be reset .

So define myList outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int zeroIndex = intArray[i];`

Hope you get it now :-)